# MySQL Union - Select data from first table in union first

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT service.*
FROM star_service
INNER JOIN service ON service.code = star_service.service

UNION

SELECT service.*
FROM service
```

How can I modify the above query so that the results from the first table are shown first followed by the second query in the union?

Comment: add a dummy value 1 to first select list, and value 2 to second. Order by that column.

Comment: @jarlh if you see the comment to my answer - OP needs deduping, but 1, 2 (good idea) will allow dupes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an additional column to the result set, then use that column to for ordering.

Like this:

```
SELECT service.*, 1 as OBCol
FROM star_service
INNER JOIN service ON service.code = star_service.service

UNION

SELECT service.*, 2 as OBCol
FROM service

ORDER BY OBCol
```

Answer (score 2):

I would skip the `union` altogether.  If you want everything from `service` with the ones in `star_service` first, then just use `left join` and `order by`:

```
select s.*
from service s left join
     star_service ss
     on s.code = ss.service
order by (ss.service is not null) desc;
```

EDIT:

If there are duplicates in `star_service`, then you are better off using `exists`:

```
select s.*, (exists (select 1 from start_service ss where s.code = ss.service) ) as in_ss
from service s
order by (is_ss is not null) desc;
```

These versions (with the proper indexes) should perform much, much better than your original version or anything with a `union`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL`, which preserves selected order of the results of the two queries in the order coded (and preserves duplicates).

Just add `ALL`:

```
SELECT service.*
FROM star_service
INNER JOIN service ON service.code = star_service.service

UNION ALL

SELECT service.*
FROM service
```

Comment: Sadly `UNION ALL` is not an option as I need to hide duplicates.

Comment: And there's no guarente the result will be select 1 first, and then select 2. (Usually it will, but SQL makes no promises without an ORDER BY clause.)

Answer (score 0):

better to go with UNION ALL instead of UNION because

union gives sorted output.

union all gives unsorted output

```
SELECT service.*
FROM star_service
INNER JOIN service ON service.code = star_service.service

UNION ALL

SELECT service.*
FROM service
```